# How to enable spdy module in nginx 1.4.1?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, spdy

I have installed nginx 1.4.1 using in ubuntu 13.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get install update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

When I run `nginx -V` it returns `nginx version: nginx/1.4.1` along with other other config details but I don't see any spdy module config.

So how can I configure spdy module post installation or I have to re-install from source and pass custom configs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SPDY module wasn’t compiled in, there is no possibility to activate it. Compiling nginx from source is very easy, so you might want to remove the stuff installed from the repository (`sudo apt-get purge nginx`) and compile it yourself with SPDY support. If you’d like a start point for compiling yourself head over to [this script](https://github.com/MovLib/www/blob/master/conf/install-scripts/nginx.sh) in one of my GitHub repos. If you’ve ever compiled something yourself it should help you. Otherwise create another question regarding compiling nginx.

**Related Weblinks**

- [ngx_http_spdy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html)

Comment: I think that following this guide: http://xdev.me/article/Recompile_Nginx_deb_package_with_a_new_module together with building the sources from the ppa, would be a even better solution. You get a deb, latest stable nginx, already tuned with debian-like distribution, and you just need to tune some parts of the build process...